# Spring oauth2 add tables prefix name

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Spring by default for oauth2 create five tables :

- oauth_access_token
- oauth_approvals
- oauth_client_details
- oauth_client_token
- oauth_code
- oauth_refresh_token

I need add prefix for that tables for example **adm_**oauth_refresh_token
Where is the option to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't mention a lot about your configuration (In fact you didn't mention a lot in general), but you can set the SQL statements with their respective setters from following classes (follow the link for source code):

- [JdbcTokenStore](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JdbcTokenStore.java)
- [JdbcApprovalStore](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/1b2ae987e9486a875b40424f18bb785baf0b898c/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/approval/JdbcApprovalStore.java)
- [JdbcClientDetailsService](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/client/JdbcClientDetailsService.java)
- [JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/1b2ae987e9486a875b40424f18bb785baf0b898c/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/code/JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices.java)
- [JdbcClientTokenServices](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/1b2ae987e9486a875b40424f18bb785baf0b898c/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/token/JdbcClientTokenServices.java)